# Program that sums things to an array

Tags: c, arrays

This book requires me to answer '' What output do you expect from the following program?''

After reading it many times I dont seem to fully understand its inner workings.

From what I get:

1. First For loop stablishes that this process is going to repeat for 10 times. Variable j is assigned to start at 0.
2. Second for loop starts the variable i at 0 and stablishes the condition i < j and does the operations written after it.

What is going on exactly? j starts at 0 and so does i, therefore numbers[j] += numbers[i] equals 2?

What happens after this operation is completed?

If i and j equal to 0 then why is this condition i < j True?

```
int main (void)
{
    int numbers[10] = { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    int i, j;

    for ( j = 0; j < 10; ++j )
        for ( i = 0; i < j; ++i )
            numbers[j] += numbers[i];

    for ( j = 0; j < 10; ++j )
        printf ("%i ", numbers[j]);

    printf ("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try running it and see what you get.  Once you have that, you should have a better understanding of what the code is doing.

Comment: And thats what I did, which confused me a lot more.

Output is: 1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16. 32, 64...

Comment: Not sure if this is the root of the confusion but note that the condition of the `for` loop is tested *before* its body is entered.

Comment: What does this numbers[j] += numbers[i]; exactly mean. 

number[ j ] is number [ 0 ], right? which is Number 1 in the Array. So what is this expression doing exactly? number [ 0 ] in the array will be number [0] + number [0]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing you have to notice is that you have the outer loop, which runs from 0 to 10 and you to something to numbers[j]. This indicates that you take each element and modify it somehow. In order to find how, by inspecting the second loop and the right hand side of the assignment, you can notice that it adds to numbers[j] all elements with indices smaller than j. Now let's see what happens in a few steps:

```
j = 0 : 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
j = 1 : 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
j = 2 : 1 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
j = 3 : 1 1 2 4 0 0 0 0 0 0
j = 4 : 1 1 2 4 8 0 0 0 0 0
```

At the end, you will get an array with the property that each element a[j] is equal to a[0] + a[1] + ... + a[j] and a[0] = 1.

Now, taking a closer look at the beginning of the process, you have j = 0 and i = 0. The second for loop runs for as long as i < j. Since this comparison is false, the loop is not executed and we go to the next iteration of the outer loop, with j = 1.